# Authentication for not all pages Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "tencet", password: "qk35lm"

  def index
    @posts = Post.order(:updated_at).reverse_order
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

end
```

But I don't want authentication for page "new", how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify `except` option because this method using `before_action` [inside](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/34d6a17d4d9690c25c686e1701103c0d70743819/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L69):

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "tencet", password: "qk35lm", except: [ :new ]
```

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic) is documentation for `http_basic_authenticate_with` helper.